# How to use ASP .NET Web API methods in a Ember.js application

Tags: asp.net, ember.js, asp.net-web-api

I'm using this Emberjs template http://www.asp.net/single-page-application/overview/templates/emberjs-template to make an ember application inside asp .net. I have developed some basic web api's using asp.net web api, but how would I call these POST, GET, etc methods from the ember application? i.e. How would I connect my ember controller, models and views to this asp .net back-end?

Comment: This fellow has a Code Project article with a complete example that explains how to do it: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/511031/A-sample-real-time-web-application-using-Ember-js

Comment: Additionally ansh, I wrote a precompiler for handlebars templates in asp.net which may prove useful.  http://www.nuget.org/packages/HandlebarsHelper/ https://github.com/kingpin2k/HandlebarsHelper/

Answer (score 2):

I blogged this issue over here http://www.emadibrahim.com/2014/04/09/emberjs-and-asp-net-web-api-and-json-serialization/ this works for GETs but working on a custom model binder to make it work for POSTs and PUTs - I will update my answer when done.

Comment: the code above and at the gist https://gist.github.com/eibrahim/10286724 is working for me - I believe my POST and PUT work out of the box without any changes.  do you have a specific question I can answer?

Comment: I think I was wrong here - I got into the trap of singular vs plural for Ember. Anyways. Thank you for getting back to me.

Comment: hi again, I have a small problem with GetRootFieldName()... I am using EF with Webapi. When the resultset is blank from the database, the code is failing. I have tried with  type = Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(value).GetType() also and it is not working. It work perfectly when there is some data. However, for blank it is just a mess. How can get the type when there is no record returned in the dbset.

Comment: Got the solution use ; type.GetGenericArguments()[0].Name

Here is the code now... 

if (Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(value) != null)
                    {
                        type = Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(value).GetType();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        type = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                    }

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Ember.js [getting started guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/). After you have your application set up, you could use Ember Data to communicate with your back end. If you follow conventions it's as easy as swapping out your adapter for `DS.RESTAdapter`